# C - System call - Bug in read/write struct

Tags: c, system, system-calls

In order to complete a project, I've to "create" a dynamic HDD using a file (i'll call him FDD). this file contains in first place an addressing table, containing off_t of an inode.
An inode contains n off_t, each represent the beginning of a cluster in the file.

That works fine !

Then, i add an option to delete files contained in the FDD. To avoid too large hole, i save them in an addressing table (called "void table") which know where are the hole and how big they are.

That doesn't work actually ... in fact, when i delete a file, i notice it to my void tables, it adds the hole pretty well, exept at the end, my table is completely corrupted (with value like "47878465" ....). My FDD also takes brutally more than 400GB (when it should be about 3kB), dont know why ...

Here the "void table" .c and .h
The fail came from the function "ajouterVide", exactly where i wrote the English comment.

__*_*__*_*__*_*__.h

```
`typedef struct{

    int taille[NTAB];
    off_t vide[NTAB];
    off_t next;
    off_t mypos;

}vide;`
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "virtualFS.h"
#include "inode.h"
#include "inode_t.h"
#include "table.h"
#include "table_t.h"
#include "tableVide.h"

vide* creerVide(){  
    int i;
    vide* v = (vide*)malloc(sizeof(vide));
    v->next = -1;
    v->mypos = sizeof(table);

    for(i=0; i<NTAB; i++){
        v->vide[i] = -1;
        v->taille[i] = 0;
    }

    return v;
}

void freeVide(vide** v){
    free(*v);
    *v = NULL;
}

off_t saveVide(int fd, vide* v){

    off_t curr = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);

    if(curr == -1){
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(write(fd, v->taille, sizeof(int) * NTAB) == -1){
        perror("Ecriture n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(write(fd, v->vide, sizeof(off_t) * NTAB) == -1){
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(write(fd, &v->next, sizeof(off_t)) == -1){
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(write(fd, &v->mypos, sizeof(off_t)) == -1){
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return curr;
}

vide* loadVide(int fd){

    vide* v = creerVide();

    if(read(fd, v->taille, sizeof(int) * NTAB) == -1){
        perror("Lecteure1 vide");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(read(fd, v->vide, sizeof(off_t) * NTAB) == -1){
        perror("Lecture vide");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(read(fd, &v->next, sizeof(off_t)) == -1){
        perror("Lecture vide");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(read(fd, &v->mypos, sizeof(off_t)) == -1){
        perror("Lecture vide");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return v;
}

vide* rechercherTableVide(int fd, int* indice){

    int ind = 0;
    vide* v, * newv;

    lseek(fd, 0 , SEEK_SET);
    loadTable(fd);
    v = loadVide(fd);
    afficherVide(v);

    while(v->vide[ind] != -1){
        if(ind == NTAB){
            ind = 0;
            if(v->next != -1){
                lseek(fd, v->next, SEEK_SET);
                freeVide(&v);
                v = loadVide(fd);
            }else{
                newv = videEnfant(fd, v);
                freeVide(&v);
                v = newv;
            }
        }else
            ind++;
    }

    *indice = ind;
    return v;
}

void ajouterVide(int fd, inode* i, off_t pos){

    int j, ind = 0;
    vide* v = NULL;
    size_t taille;

    for(j=0; j<NBLOCK; j++){
        if(i->tab_ad[j] == -1)
            j = NBLOCK;
        else{
            v = rechercherTableVide(fd, &ind);
            v->vide[ind] = i->tab_ad[j];

            if(j == NBLOCK-1 || i->tab_ad[j + 1] == -1) /*On est au dernier bloc, potentiellement plus petit*/
                taille = i->taille % TBLOCK;
            else{
                int jj;
                taille = TBLOCK;

                for(jj=j; jj<NBLOCK-1; jj++){
                    if(contigue(i->tab_ad[jj], TBLOCK, i->tab_ad[jj+1]) == 1){
                        if(jj == NBLOCK-2 || i->tab_ad[jj+2] == -1)
                            taille += i->taille % TBLOCK;
                        else
                            taille += TBLOCK;
                        j++;    
                    }else
                        jj = NBLOCK;
                }           
            }
            v->taille[ind] = taille;
            lseek(fd, v->mypos, SEEK_SET);
            saveVide(fd, v);
            /*If i load / save / load / save many times, its always Ok here*/
            freeVide(&v);
        }
    }

    v = rechercherTableVide(fd, &ind);
    /*Here its completly fucked :( */
    v->vide[ind] = pos;     
    v->taille[ind] = tailleInode(i);
    lseek(fd, v->mypos, SEEK_SET);
    saveVide(fd, v);
    freeVide(&v);
}

int contigue(off_t d1, size_t taille, off_t d2){
    return d1 + (off_t)taille == d2 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? Posting a wall of code, with most of the files missing, at that, and asking people what's wrong with it is not particularly productive.

Comment: Data being "completely corrupted" suggests a pointer or array-bounds error somewhere. Add periodic printouts or tests to detect when it's becoming corrupted, and figure out exactly what you're doing between when it was good and when it wasn't. Add more tests/printouts as necessary until you've narrowed it down to a particular operation. Analyze that, operator by operator if necessary, until you've found and fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found an explanation to the problem. It is cause by the Data structure alignement, i 've succeed to solve the problem :)

Thanks for everything.